# Gitlab web interface does not let me edit files

Tags: gitlab

I've installed on a fresh installation of CentOS 6.5 x64 the stable version 7.0.0 of Gitlab Omnibus.

I've then copied inside `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories` the content of my old Gitlab repositories (I was running an Ubuntu machine with Gitlab installed from git).

There was an error when I tried to edit some file from the web interface:

```
Your changes could not be committed, because the file has been changed.
```

And I was getting a 500 error if I edit a wiki page.

I've then tried this command:

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:satellites:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

And my wiki pages was now editable but the same error was returned if I edit some repository file.

I've then tried deleting the content of `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/gitlab-satellites/` but the problem was not fixed.

Now If I try to run `gitlab-rake gitlab:satellites:create RAILS_ENV=production` I get:

```
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'production' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]

Tasks: TOP => gitlab:satellites:create => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Mi repositories have as owner `git:git` and permissions `drwsrws---.`

How can I fix these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem.

I've ran

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

and manually fixed every error reported there. Now everything works.